# R: What is the difference between "<-" and "<<-" assignment operators?

Tags: r, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

As an R user, I'm used to the typical "<-" operator. However, I recently encountered operator "<<-". (It's from other people's code, therefore I cannot freely copy-paste it herein.)
It appears they are equivalent, but I wonder if there is any difference between the two.

Comment: <<- assigns a variable in the global environment, to be used anywhere

Comment: @user2974951 and with extreme caution ;-)

Comment: @user2974951 It assigns only to the global environment if the variable is not found in a previous enclosing environment.

Comment: @Leevo Either these other people are quite advanced R programmers or they don't know what they are doing.